# getting all possible cases in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.5

Say I have a list of n elements, and each element consists of list of 0 or more integers, I want to get all possible combinations.

This is my list:

```
[[0], [1, 6], [2, 3], [2, 3], [], [4]]
```

This is expected output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 4]
[0, 1, 3, 2, 4]
...
[0, 6, 3, 3, 4]
```

List order should be kept. That is any combination should be started with 0.

Comment: It would help if you defined what a "case" was, and included what you have tried so far.

Comment: case is list of integer, according to my list.

Comment: make a case using all item in my list. but order should be kept

Comment: @LeeJaeng: that tells us nothing. I can **guess** what you mean, but 'according to your list' could be a manual arrangement, because you didn't describe the *rules* by which your output is produced.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I see. my english skill is not enough describing all things.. T^T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the *product* of the lists; use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but do filter out empty lists first:

```
from itertools import product

for combo in product(*filter(None, yourlist)):
    print(combo)
```

`filter(None, ...)` removes any empty elements.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> yourlist = [[0], [1, 6], [2, 3], [2, 3], [], [4]]
>>> for combo in product(*filter(None, yourlist)):
...     print(combo)
...
(0, 1, 2, 2, 4)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
(0, 1, 3, 2, 4)
(0, 1, 3, 3, 4)
(0, 6, 2, 2, 4)
(0, 6, 2, 3, 4)
(0, 6, 3, 2, 4)
(0, 6, 3, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but it filter out empty list.

Comment: @LeeJaeng that's intended. A cartesian product with an empty iterable as argument can only produce the empty list.

Comment: @LeeJaeng: what did you expect the empty list to contribute to the product? With empty lists in there, you'd get an *empty* product, which is why it needs to be filtered out.

Comment: @LeeJaeng: see, the number of combinations produced is the same as the product of the lengths of the inputs. If you leave the empty list in, you get 1 x 2 x 2 x 0 x 4 == 0 outputs. Remove the empty list and you get 1 x 2 x 2 x 4 == 8 outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Throw out any empty list and then apply `itertools.product`.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lst = [[0], [1, 6], [2, 3], [2, 3], [], [4]]
>>> list(product(*[x for x in lst if x]))
[(0, 1, 2, 2, 4), (0, 1, 2, 3, 4), (0, 1, 3, 2, 4), (0, 1, 3, 3, 4), (0, 6, 2, 2, 4), (0, 6, 2, 3, 4), (0, 6, 3, 2, 4), (0, 6, 3, 3, 4)]
```

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) will compute the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) for the given iterables. If the iterables you provide are ordered (which is the case for your lists), the tuples which `product` creates will reflect that order, too.